# SwiftUI return type Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Foundation.Date' to return type 'BarCharts.Date'

Tags: swift, swiftui, types

I am doing a bar chart in my SwiftUI app, however I encountered a problem...

```
struct ViewMonth: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let date: Date
    let viewCount: Int
}
```

I defined several variable types in the above code.

```
struct Date {
    static func from(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date {
        let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day)
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
    }
}
```

It seems like I can't convert the expression type 'Foundation.Date' to 'BarCharts.Date'. I don't understand the error message. Please help!

I expect the code will yield no errors.

Comment: Hint: The error message tells you _exactly_ what you are trying to do. Take it at face value. It complains about what you do, not what you intend to do. YOU are trying to convert to Barcharts.Date.

Answer (score 1):

The error complains about a terminology conflict of your type `Date` with existing `Date` in `Foundation`.

Basically there are three options:

1. Replace `struct Date` with `extension Date`.
2. Rename your struct `Date` as something which does not interfere with any type in the `Foundation` framework.
3. Declare all instances of your custom type as `BarCharts.Date`.

I recommend the first option.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types: Foundation.Date is the date type that everyone uses. And I suppose you defined your struct Date inside a class Barcharts, so it is a Barcharts.Date.

The “from” function is declared to return Date - which is a shortcut for Barcharts.Date. Now the error message should make sense. It’s up to you to decide what you wanted it to return.